# How to set a default marker to the location based lat and long in google map received by Google Static API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want google map image with default marker like below.
[image]

But, It is coming naked with marker. Click below link

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=28.6086154,77.3566754&zoom=14&markers=color:blue&size=500x250&key=YOUR_API_KEY

[image]

How can I set marker same as previous photo??

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the color of the marker to `red`, plus add the marker location at the end. Here’s a Static Map API web request for reference:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=28.6086154,77.3566754&zoom=14&size=500x250&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7C28.6086154,77.3566754&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

More info can be found here:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#MarkerStyles
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#MarkerLocations